# Can we add a parameter to the url that we launch to execute a Java class (a servlet in fact) on Tomcat?

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet. In the `doGet` method, I wrote a code that inserts data in an Oracle database (that code uses Hibernate).

Everything works fine, I launch the url on Tomcat like that:

```
http://localhost:8080/Coctos/insertion
```

Then data is inserted in my database.

**But now, I would want to add a parameter to the url**. For example, I want to add a String. Then I will use this String within the `doGet` method to insert that particular String in a table of my database.

Or this String may also refer to the name of the table that I want to insert data in...

So, eventually, what I want is adding information in my Url then use this information to perform different tasks according to the information given.

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: like this: `http://localhost:8080/Coctos/insertion?parameter=value&another=one`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly it's possible. Just add a request parameter to your URL.
`http://localhost:8080/Coctos/insertion?value=foobar`

You can get it from `HttpServletRequest` with the `getParameter(String name)` method in your servlet.

Note that you should probably be using `POST` instead of `GET` for something like this, and that there are security issues that you need to consider if the URL is available to the outside world.

Comment: Is there a way to send `POST` data instead of sending it in a `<form`?

Comment: A form is the standard way of doing POST requests with a browser, but of course there are tools you can use to make POST requests to your server (such as `curl`).

Comment: Ok thanks, so i will use `POST` instead. But how to secure the url ? Should I use `HTTPS` or something like that ?

Comment: Well, `HTTPS` will keep the data safe from network sniffing. You also need to consider how you're using the parameters that you receive. Since the users can put anything they want there, you'll have to make sure that they do SQL injections etc.

Comment: That they **don't** do SQL injections of course.. :)